# How to parse the sentence?

Tags: meaning

> The surge in its shares ***of*** triggered the market's circuit breakers
>   and trade was halted after a 44% jump in early session.

I think the sentence above is wrong, and it should delete the word "of".

I parse the sentence like this :

> The surge / in it shares / triggered / the market's circuit breakers
>   / and / trade / was halted / after a 44% jump / in early session.

Comment: Some (intelligently challenged) people replace "have" with "of", because they don't know better. Depending on the source, maybe this is the case here.

Comment: @npst Can you give me more information of the source that people replace "have" with "of"?

Comment: @user48070 *Of* and unstressed *have* are typically homophones, so there's no way to tell them apart in speech from sound alone.  As a result, some people mix them up in writing: [you'll see mistakes like *\*would of* and *\*could of* fairly frequently](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/couldof.html).

Comment: @snailplane So you mean "would of" and "could of" are wrong??

Comment: @user48070 Yes.

Comment: "The surge in its shares of triggered the market's circuit breakers and trade was halted after a 44% jump in early session." This sentence is from the Wall Street Journal, but it is wrong?

Comment: @user48070 Yes.  I agree with StoneyB's answer: *of* should be deleted.  This is probably not the same kind of error in *\*would of* or *\*could of*, however, because the version of the sentence with *have* is unlikely.

Comment: I agree, this does not seem to be some highschoolers error. More likely some leftover from a different sentence structure or something.

Answer (score 5):

As you correctly discern, *of* is an error here and should be deleted.

Some respondents suggest that this is a common uneducated mis-spelling of *have*, and that is possible; but I think it very unlikely. A present perfect is not exactly ungrammatical here, but it fits awkwardly with the past form in the following clause: a present perfect suggests that the topic is the current result of the surge, but the past tense suggests that the topic is its past result.

A simpler explanation is that the author (or a later editor, updating a developing story with later events) was working with some such phrase as “surge in shares of more than 15%” and failed to delete the *of* when revising.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trend to replace *have* with *of* in sentences.  This is what appears to have happened here.

This has come about from spoken speech where expressions like *Should have* become elided to *Should've* then erroneously expanded again to *Should of*.

To propagate this error into writing is frowned upon but your interpretation of deleting the *of* is correct.